# How can i remove backslash(\) in regex charechter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I need help about regex charecter.

I will remove or hidden the backslash if I search with regex charecter.

```js
  const handleSearchChange = ({ target }: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    setSearchText(target.value.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'));
  };
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2ISY.png)

Comment: You should provide a [mcve]. You have a live demo showing a function, but it errors because you've written it in TypeScript and haven't turned Babel on. You also never call it, don't show what input you give it and don't show what output you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove backslash in any of the below way. replace function will remove only the first backslash. But split function will work for every backslash.

```
  let text = 'my\\test\\text';
  console.log(text);
  text = text.replace('\\', '');
  console.log(text);
  text = 'my\\test\\text';
  text = text.split('\\').join('');
  console.log(text);
```